# jQuery: is there any difference between $.ajaxSetup(beforeSend) and $(document).ajaxSend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Using jQuery (v2.1.4), is there any difference between these two methods?

**1) [$.ajaxSetup(beforeSend)](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/)**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
    // whatever you need to do before
    // any jQuery Ajax request is sent
  }
});
```

**2) [$(document).ajaxSend](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/)**

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, jqXHR, settings) {
  // whatever you need to do before
  // any jQuery Ajax request is sent
});
```

Is there any reason to prefer one over the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From jQuery [`$.ajaxSetup()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) documentation:

> All subsequent Ajax calls using any function will use the new settings, unless overridden by the individual calls, until the next invocation of $.ajaxSetup().

The `$.ajaxSetup()` does something like this:

```
ajaxExtend(jQuery.ajaxSettings, target);
```

From [`$.ajaxSend()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/) documentation:

> Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent, jQuery triggers the ajaxSend event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the .ajaxSend() method are executed at this time.

And the jQuery source for `$.ajaxSend()`:

```
function (fn) {
    return this.on(type, fn);
}
```

So, basically the `$(document).ajaxSend()` adds an event listener to all the document where you can make any handler to execute anytime a jQuery Ajax call is about to be sent (the handler intercepts it, but [`XMLHttpRequest.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) value is already `1` - "Opened").

This means that if `$.ajax()` is called with the `global` option set to `false`, the `ajaxSend()` method will not fire.

While on the `$.ajaxSetup()` you are in fact creating defaults for every single jQuery Ajax call's settings, and the callback defined through the `beforeSend` option will always be called (`XMLHttpRequest.readyState` value is `0` - "Unsent").

Comment: The question is not about `$.ajaxSetup()` itself but registering a `beforeSend` handler with `$.ajaxSetup()` - `$.ajaxSetup({beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {...}})` compared to `$(document).ajaxSend(...)`

Comment: @Andreas it was kinda implicit when I said it will overwrite the default settings. Edited to be more clear. Thanks

Comment: Hi @JoelAlmeida, thanks for the quick reply! Just a quick question to clarify what you say: if a jQuery Ajax request has a `beforeSend` callback configured in the options (let's call it "x"), and `$(document).ajaxSend()` also is configured with a callback (let's call it "y"), will both callbacks ("x" and "y") be executed before sending out the request, and if so in what order? Cheers  :)

Comment: the callback `x` will execute before the callback `y`

Comment: Ok, sounds like we have a good answer! Before accepting it, I'll just add an edit to include the `global` option mentioned in @RohitKumar answer, which imho is a relevant point. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: @JoelAlmeida actually I just noticed there's a contradiction in your answer: for `$.ajaxSetup` first you cite jQuery docs "unless overridden by the individual calls", then you say "it will overwrite the settings". I checked: the first statement is true, the second one is false. I'll include a correction to this point in the edits.

Comment: @Pensierinmusica yep. small confusion on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Both do very similar function , but it always depend on the need
There are some key points , on which you may focus

1. ajaxSend() method, must be attached to document only.
2. if `$.ajax()` is called with the global option set to false, the `ajaxSend()` method will not fire.
3. the `beforeSend` option will be called regardless of the type of request.

From the perspective of priority, you can use in such a manner, do all setup options in `ajaxSend` and for custom or specific ajax request override it with `beforeSend` in `$.ajax()`.

**HTML**

```
<body>

<div><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>

<button id="btn1">Change Content</button>
<button id="btn2">Change Content Override</button>

</body>
```

**JS**

```
   $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, opt){
        $("div").append("<p>Requesting " + opt.url + "</p>");
    });
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("div").load("yourpage.html");
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        global: false,
        beforeSend:function(){$("div").append("<p>Overriding</p>");}
        });
    $("div").load("yourpage.html");
    });
```

**LIVE** http://jsfiddle.net/mailmerohit5/w8t44247/

Answer (score 0):

From JQuery's documentation:

> There are two types of events:
>
> **Local Events**
>      These are callbacks that you can subscribe to within the Ajax request
>      object, like so:

```
 $.ajax({
     beforeSend: function(){
     // Handle the beforeSend event
  },
     complete: function(){
     // Handle the complete event
  }
  // ......
});
```

> Global Events
>
> These events are triggered on the document, calling any handlers which
>   may be listening. You can listen for these events like so:

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
   $("#loading").show();
 }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
   $("#loading").hide();
 });
```

> Global events can be disabled for a particular Ajax request by passing in the global option, like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    global: false,
    // ...
});
```

[for more information](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)